# Discriminant analysis with R: no proportion of trace shown

Tags: r, dfa

This my very first R-analysis and I am having problems with the output of a discriminant analysis (which was the follow-up of a significant manova).

Here is the Code:

```
MimicryDFA<-lda(Bedingung ~ Similarity + Liking, data = d)
MimicryDFA
```

which lead to this output:
[DFA Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpQos.jpg)

My problem is that it does not show the "proportion of trace" which should tell me how much variance is explained by the coefficients (according to Andy Fields). Can someone help?

Here is the data I have:
[Data DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3eYb.jpg)

Comment: try: `MimicryDFA$svd` - the singular values, which give the ratio of the between- and within-group standard deviations on the linear discriminant variables. Their squares are the canonical F-statistics.

Comment: Thank you @missuse! The function gave me the value 6.882697. But I dont get what it says, is there a way to get the "Total variance explained" out of this?

Comment: This `lda$svd` explains the ratio of  between- and within-group variation. For total variance explained check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67342/proportion-of-explained-variance-in-pca-and-lda). Additionally Cross Validated is a better place to ask such a question. This site is about solving code problems.

Comment: For LDA the proportion of the "discriminatory variance explained" would be: `(lda$svd^2)/sum((lda$svd^2)`. In case of 1 dimension like yours this is equal to 1 or 100%

Comment: great @missuse! Thank you for that link, that helped a lot :) Also I've registered on that site :)

Answer (score 0):

This question, and comments, were useful to me. The Proportion of Trace is not stored, but rather only shown as output. As already explained by @missuse at comments, it can be calculated with `$svd`.

```
model_lda <- MASS::lda(  iris[,-5] , grouping=iris[,5] )

Proportion_of_trace <- model_lda$svd^2/sum(model_lda$svd^2)
Proportion_of_trace

Proportion_of_trace <- proportions( modelo_lda$svd^2 )
# proportions() or prop.table()
Proportion_of_trace <- prop.table( model_lda$svd^2 )
Proportion_of_trace
```

```
[1] 0.991212605 0.008787395
[1] 0.991212605 0.008787395
```